# How do I include another table with an inner join statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a functional query using several inner join statements. It combines tables events, venues, and categories just fine. I also have a "favorites" table which I'm planning to include as well, but I'm having trouble with the logic.

My table looks like this:

```
favorites:
ID accountID eventID
1  2         14
2  2         16 
3  3         18
4  3         14
...
```

and continues.
The ID is a unique ID (not relevant here), the accountID is the user to which it's associated, and the eventID is the event which has been favorited.

Essentially, I want to know, for each event I present in my code, whether it's been favorited.

This is my code right now, which works, but doesn't yet contain the favorites info.

```
SELECT 
    e.ID, 
    e.Title,
    v.Name as venue, 
    v.Address,
    v.Email,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.Name SEPARATOR '  &middot;  ') as Categories
FROM 
    Events e
    INNER JOIN Venues v ON e.VenueID = v.ID
    INNER JOIN EventCategories ec ON ec.EventID = e.ID
    INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.ID = ec.CategoryID
WHERE
e.ID = ".$_GET['e']." 
GROUP BY 
    e.Title, e.Start, v.Name
ORDER BY 
    e.Start ASC
```

What I've tried was code like

```
INNER JOIN favorites f ON f.eventID = e.ID
```

and

```
INNER JOIN favorites f ON e.ID = f.eventID
```

but that just causes everything to break.

I played with different variants of this but haven't had much success. I'm new to writing queries and I'd say this is a complicated one.

I get accountID from a session variable (if the person is logged in).

What I'd like to do is get a result like "if favorites exists, then run this script" or "return 1 if favorited, 0 if not" so that I can base my output on whether or not this event appears in this list. (I'm gonna put a heart icon next to ones which are favorited.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Kinda sounds like what you want is a `LEFT JOIN`.  Also, do try to be more specific than statements like "but that just causes everything to break".  Tell us what _does_ happen.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. Then compose a new overall query. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: You don't say how output is a function of input. "for each event [...] whether it's been favorited" is vague. Wrong code cannot tell us what you want. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly". When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you are trying to do, you can add a case statement inside the select to see if the event id is even in the table, if it is then it has been favorited.

```
SELECT 
    e.ID, 
    e.Title,
    v.Name as venue, 
    v.Address,
    v.Email,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.Name SEPARATOR '  &middot;  ') as Categories,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Favorites WHERE EventID = e.ID) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS HasBeenFavorited
FROM 
    Events e
    INNER JOIN Venues v ON e.VenueID = v.ID
    INNER JOIN EventCategories ec ON ec.EventID = e.ID
    INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.ID = ec.CategoryID
WHERE
    e.ID = ".$_GET['e']." 
ORDER BY 
    e.Start ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think thal all you need is to add a 'Left Join' to your original query like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.ID, 
    e.Title,
    v.Name as venue, 
    v.Address,
    v.Email,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.Name SEPARATOR '  &middot;  ') as Categories,
    CASE WHEN F.EventID IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1 END AS HasFavorite
FROM 
    Events e
    INNER JOIN Venues v ON e.VenueID = v.ID
    INNER JOIN EventCategories ec ON ec.EventID = e.ID
    INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.ID = ec.CategoryID
    LEFT JOIN Favorites F on F.EventID = e.ID
WHERE
    e.ID = ".$_GET['e']." 
ORDER BY 
    e.Start ASC
```

Comment: Eduardo Silva, thanks for your response! The other responses were helpful, but your idea to do the Left Join worked perfectly. Thanks!